# How to export Eclipse RAP application into WAR with gradle script

Tags: ant, gradle, war, eclipse-rap

Eclipse has for exporting RAP application to WAR wizard so called `Eclipse WAR Product export wizard` which is available as `WAR Products (Incubation)` bundle `org.eclipse.libra.warproducts.feature.feature.group`.

Does anybody know about `ant` or `gradle` script to achieve same thing `RAP to WAR`

Answer (score 1):

In the RAP project, we create WAR files for the demos in the [nightly build](http://git.eclipse.org/c/rap/org.eclipse.rap.git/tree/releng/org.eclipse.rap.examples.build/controlsdemo/pom.xml). It's a Maven/Tycho build, but maybe it's helpful as an example anyway.

Comment: would be nice to have also other scripts so people could integrate easily to build engines...

Comment: IMHO: Gradle or ant should be supported, gradle started to be very popular (its been used everywhere), and its much easy to write/read gradle based scripts... Now when WUFF gradle plugin exist, at least RCP plugin can be built by gradle... I can do my script for exporting RAP to war, but not sure if it could be used for general purpose